# Probabilistic interpretation of sum of quantile functions

Tags: probability, distributions, quantiles, mixture-distribution

We know that the weighted sum of CDF
$$
F(x) = w_1 F_1(x) + w_2 F_2(x), \,\, w_1 + w_2 = 1
$$
is the CDF of the mixture distribution.

Is there a probabilistic interpretation for weighted sum of quantile functions below?
$$
Q(p) = v_1 Q_1(p) + v_2 Q_2(p) = v_1 F_1^{-1}(p) + v_2 F_2^{-1}(p), \,\, v_1>0 , v_2 > 0,p\in[0,1]
$$

Answer (score 4):

It's always hard to prove a negative. However, I have never seen such an interpretation. The naive idea that the weighted sum of quantiles would be the corresponding quantile of the mixture distribution is of course false.

I would be interested in being proven wrong and look forward to downvotes (and actual such interpretations).